# Webpack, MD5 and VueJs

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, md5

I'm trying to use [jquery.md5.js](https://gist.github.com/thanashyam/2309671) 
plugin in my VueJs project but always getting

> TypeError: (0 , _jquery.md5) is not a function

or

```
ERROR in ./src/utils-convenience/jquery.md5.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (23:2)
21 | /*global unescape, jQuery */
22 | export default {
23 |   (function ($) {
   |   ^
24 |       'use strict';
25 | 
26 |       /*
```

I use Webpack in my project but it's not my best part so I guess there are something wrong with files import. Please advise.

Here is my code for both cases:

```
 import axios from 'axios'
 import { API_URL } from '../../config/constants'
 import { md5 } from '../utils-convenience/jquery.md5'

 export default {
  // Getting data for main-page
   getEvents () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var authId = 'api.kassy.ru'
      var secretKey = 'a619d974658f3e749b2d88b215baea46'
      var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><request 
      module="subdivision" format="json"><filter id="" db="" state="" 
      /><auth id="' + authId + '" /></request>'
      var sign = md5(xml + secretKey)
      axios.post(API_URL, {
        headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
         'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
       },
        body: {
        'xml': xml,
        'sign': sign
       }
      })
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result)
        return resolve(result.data)
      })
       .catch(err => reject(err))
    })
  }
```

So the first error appears if I do not export code from jquery.md5.js and just import this file. The second error appears if I export code as follows:

```
export default {
 (function ($) {
   'use strict';

     ///MD5 code

  }(typeof jQuery === 'function' ? jQuery : this));
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
export default {
 (function ($) {
   'use strict';

     ///MD5 code

  }(typeof jQuery === 'function' ? jQuery : this));
 }
```

This is not valid javascript. Remove the { that follows 'export default'.

```
export default 
 (function ($) {
   'use strict';

     ///MD5 code

  }(typeof jQuery === 'function' ? jQuery : this));
```